# How do I Reuse an InjectionToken with a different provider

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a string value that I provide to lib X via an `OpaqueToken`:

```
// main.module.ts
providers: [
  { provide: LIB_X_TOKEN, useValue: myValue }
]
```

Now I have a lib Y that needs the same value, but via a different token and in a different module, so I provide it like that:

```
// sub.module.ts
providers: [
  { provide: LIB_Y_TOKEN, useValue: myValue }
]
```

I want to reuse the value provided by `LIB_X_TOKEN` in `sub.module.ts` to reduce duplication. I have tried doing this:

```
// sub.module.ts
providers: [
  { provide: LIB_Y_TOKEN, value: LIB_X_TOKEN }
]
```

but, as you can see in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fv8VhC5VEo9bWWxvprZi?p=preview), it didn't work as expected.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to create an alias for the token.

```
{ provide: LIB_Y_TOKEN, useExisting: LIB_X_TOKEN }
```

[useExisting](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#useexistingthe-alias-provider)